# C# 多言語対応する場合のUnicodeのエンコーディングは何が良いかを教えて下さい。

Tags: c#, winforms

C# Windows Formsアプリ開発で多言語対応を進めており、
データベース側(Oracle)の文字コードも含めUnicodeで多言語に対応します。

ただ、Unicodeといってもいくつかエンコーディングの方法(UTF-8,UTF-16）が
あると思います。

ユニコードで多言語対応する場合、エンコーディングの方法は何が適しているのか
知見のある方、ご教示ください。

現状、データベース、アプリ共にUTF-8を前提としようと考えております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C#自身は`string`型（.NET Frameworkにて`System.String`クラス）が提供されていますので、それを利用することをお勧めします。
その上で、データベースはデータベースで推奨されるエンコーディングを選択すべきです。例えばSQL Serverでは[Unicodeのサポート](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support#span-data-ttu-id39855-231a-nameunicodedefna-unicode-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B5%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88spanspan-classsxs-lookupspan-data-stu-id39855-231a-nameunicodedefna-unicode-supportspanspan)の項目にて

> 複数の言語を反映する文字データを格納する場合は、非Unicodeデータ型 (`char`、`varchar`、および`text`) ではなく、Unicodeデータ型 (`nchar`、`nvarchar`、および`ntext`) を常に使用してください。

と説明されています。OracleにもOracleでの適切な選択肢が提示されていることと思います。

「アプリ」につきましては何を指しているのかわかりませんでした。

Comment: ありがとうございます。UTF-8、UTF-16どちらにもメリット、デメリットがあり
それを踏まえて選択する必要がありそうですね。アプリは、アプリで扱う文字コードがあると思い記載しましたが、
Visual Studioで開発しますが、外部からのinput、outputが
無い限り文字コードの部分はあまり意識しなくて良いですよね。

当然DBへの読み書きはありますが、それはOracleがうまいこと
やってくれると認識しております。